# Wiped everything with TWRP, re-flashed CM13 and filled the internal storage with dummy data. Is my data now gone?

Tags: security, factory-reset, twrp

I sold my OnePlus One and needed to remove files from the internal storage and re-install CM13. I deleted all photos and videos by hand in Windows. Then I selected all the options available inside TWRP and wiped it. After, I installed CM13 from an image. Then I filled the phone in Windows with dummy data by copying. My phone was not encrypted before wiping.

Can I consider my data more or less gone? I'd imagine at least most of the photos and videos are gone with overwriting but what about application data such as SMS, Facebook etc. messages? If they're still on the phone, how hard would it be to bring them back to life?

Comment: Honestly, you need to look at this logically, first off, the chances any purchaser of the device would attempt to recover your data is near zero even if you just did a simple factory reset... But if they did attempt it the best they could do would be recover a few files or pictures... The chances of recovering other data like apps or settings is much more remote... The extra steps you took would prevent all but the most elite hacker or forensics lab from being able to recover any usable data of any kind. That said, with sufficient knowledge and resources, any data is recoverable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have performed a clean wipe before you flashed the rom `CM13` . At this point the data related to your apps are already gone. @acejavelin made a correct point. Recovering that data is near 0.